# Install shibboleth timeout in centos

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7, shibboleth

I am trying to install Shibboleth via ansible in a centos-7 machine which is hosted in AWS.

But am getting "`Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds`" error for installing Shibboleth and all its dependencies. I tired manually also with the command "`sudo yum -y install shibboleth`", but same error.

If I install any other package via ansible or manually are working.

I tries all of the following solutions, but no luck.

```
Reboot machine

sudo yum clean all

sudo yum clean metadata

sudo yum --disableplugin=fastestmirror update

sudo yum-complete-transaction 

sudo yum clean all && sudo yum makecache

Adding  minrate=1, timeout=300 to yum.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue on Centos-7 hosted in us-east-1. There is some discussion of build service mirroring problems on the repository config generation page. When you use that form to generate a shibboleth.repo configuration there's also a comment suggesting an another workaround:

`# If the mirrors stop working, change download to downloadcontent...`

I updated the baseUrl and gpg in the repo content as below and my error got resolved.

```
[security_shibboleth]
name=Shibboleth (CentOS_7)
type=rpm-md
baseurl=http://downloadcontent.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/shibboleth/CentOS_7/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://downloadcontent.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/shibboleth/CentOS_7/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
```

Answer (score 0):

One can directly use https://shibboleth.net site instead of OpenSuse repositories, as older packages in these repositories gets removed over time.

**Steps**:

**1.** Go to **https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/** and click **generate** repo configuration based on your OS type(**CentOS, RHEL, Amazon Linux, Rocky Linux**).

**2.** Create the Shibboleth repository & copy-paste repo configuration:

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/shibboleth.repo
```

For CentOS 7:

```
   [shibboleth]  
   name=Shibboleth (CentOS_7)  
   # Please report any problems to https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/jira 
   mirrorlist=https://shibboleth.net/cgi-bin/mirrorlist.cgi/CentOS_7
   gpgcheck=1  
   gpgkey=https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/repomd.xml.key  
        https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/cantor.repomd.xml.key  
   enabled=1
```

**2.** Update the repositories with:

```
   sudo yum update -y
```

**3.** Discover your architecture:

```
   echo "My Arch: $(cat /etc/redhat-release) ($(arch))"
```

**4.** Install Shibboleth Service Provider:

```
   yum install shibboleth.x86_64 -y
```

SP will be available in directory: `/etc/shibboleth`